# Ideas for Reducing Problem Dimension in Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, dimensional-analysis

Suppose I have a "black box" function $f: \mathbb{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{U} \subset \mathbb{R}^6$and I start with an initial guess $x \in \mathbb{U} = (a,b,c,d,e,f). $ I have already written an optimization algorithm that finds the global optimum of this problem. However, I've noticed that usually one or more of the elements in the initial guess (so either a, b, c...) remains unchanged from its value in the initial guess to its value in the global optimum. Essentially this means that I could have run the optimization algorithm at a lower dimension than 6 (which would save enormous amounts of time). My question is how can I determine which variables are essentially irrelevant before I run my algorithm? NOTE: Just because a variable remains unchanged does not mean it has no effect on the value of the function. It just doesn't change from the initial guess to the optimum.

Comment: If $a$, $b$ remain unchanged, make another initial guess with $a'\ne a$, $b'\ne b$ and check whether you get the same optimum – just to make sure that there is no flaw in your algorithm.

Comment: The algorithm is correct; just trying to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will be of any interest to you but I give you here some experience I had with large optimizations of chemical plants (hundreds of variables) using simulation.

I built an elimination procedure based on the derivative analysis. The variables I used to eliminate were those which derivatives were the smallest during the base case (first cycle of the optimizer). But, what I also noticed is that this elimination procedure was to be used in conjunction with Broyden; otherwise, equality or inequality specifications may not be possible.

Comment: I do not know if this is just a reformulation, thus no separate answer: Compute the gradient in the initial point, for instance using the reverse mode of automatic differentiation. If there is a magnitude difference between groups of partial derivatives in the gradient, optimize first along the group of variables with the largest partials. Revise this grouping decision regularly. -- If "eliminate" means "set to constant", this should really be the same.

Comment: @LutzL. I fully agree with you. This is exactly what I was doing : a single iteration with all variables, decide hwo many variables to eliminate (setting them to a constant value) and restart the problem.